# Binding error with PropertyChanged - Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a textbox with two way binding, but it is giving a `TargetException` error. The data does not load in the `TextBox` and when I type in it, I get this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=(local:Config.eventDateFormat); DataItem='String' (HashCode=-247125614); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='TXTB_Settings_Event_AddDateToName'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') TargetException:'System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(Object item, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object value)'
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TXTB_Settings_Event_AddDateToName"
         Text="{Binding (local:Config.eventDateFormat), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="110,200,1012,492"/>
```

Here is the class and property:

```
public class Config : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _eventDateFormat = "MMM-dd-yy-";
   public string eventDateFormat
   {
      get { return _eventDateFormat; }
      set
      {
         if (value != _eventDateFormat)
         {
            _eventDateFormat = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(eventDateFormat));
         }
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
   }
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
private string _eventDateFormat = "MMM-dd-yy-";
public string eventDateFormat
{
   get { return _eventDateFormat; }
   set
   {
      if (value != _eventDateFormat)
      {
         _eventDateFormat = value;
         Changed();
      }
   }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void Changed([CallerMemberName] string property = "") =>
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
```

DataContext for MainWindow is:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

I have a bunch of observable collections bound to other UI elements, so I can't change DataContext to just Config.  I tried binding to the grid they were in, but couldn't get that to compile.

When my Config class was static, I was able to do two way binding, not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  However, from what I've read, this class should not be static as it does get updated sometimes.

Not sure if it's relevant, I am using MahApps Metro 2.0

Using c# 4.6.1

Comment: When a Binding is created, the property name in parentheses is specified for Attached Properties.
Your eventDateFormat property is a normal property.  
And to bind to it, you must first create an instance of the Config type.  
How exactly - I can't say.  
The code you provided is not enough to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are used to [bind to attached properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview).

> To bind to an attached property, place parentheses around the attached property. For example, to bind to the attached property DockPanel.Dock, the syntax is Path=(DockPanel.Dock).

You need to remove the parentheses from the binding, as well as the namespace prefix `local`. Assuming that `Config` is a property holding an instance of your `Config` class on your main view model, the path looks like:

```
Text="{Binding Config.eventDateFormat, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

If it is not a property on your main view model, make it one, if you cannot set it as a data context explicitly anywhere. If you set a separate instance as data context you would just bind to `eventDateFormat`.

Comment: OK great.  I removed the parentheses and "local:Config" and set the datacontext to an instance of the Config class on the parent grid and it works now.